# Which items are required for the "Polyculture" achievement?

Tags: achievements, stardew-valley

Stardew Valley has a "Polyculture" achievement, which reads:

> Ship 15 of each crop.

However, it's not clear on what qualifies as a crop.  For example, a lot of the items that can be foraged can be turned into seeds and then grown from seed - do they qualify?  What about things like animal products?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A complete list can be found [here](https://www.trueachievements.com/a226743/polyculture-achievement) on what needs to be shipped:

> Spring:
>
> - Parsnip
> - Green Bean
> - Cauliflower
> - Potato
> - Kale
> - Garlic
> - Rhubarb
>
> Summer:
>
> - Melon
> - Tomato
> - Blueberry
> - Hot Pepper
> - Wheat
> - Radish
> - Starfruit
> - Hops
> - Corn
> - Red Cabbage
>
> Fall:
>
> - Eggplant
> - Pumpkin
> - Bok Choy
> - Beet
> - Yam
> - Cranberry
> - Amaranth
> - Grape
> - Artichoke

In addition, the guide also states **strawberries** (spring) and **coffee beans** (spring or summer) or also needed. A user in the comments in the guide (and here) also states that flowers are not necessary (they have been removed from the quote).

Answer (score 1):

"Crop" is anything you can grow from its specific seed, except for flowers, ancient fruits, and sweet gem berries. The full list is:

- Cauliflower
- Coffee bean
- Garlic
- Green bean
- Kale
- Parsnip
- Potato
- Rhubarb
- Strawberry
- Blueberry
- Corn
- Hops
- Hot pepper
- Melon
- Radish
- Red cabbage
- Starfruit
- Sunflower
- Tomato
- Wheat
- Amaranth
- Artichoke
- Beet
- Bok choy
- Cranberry
- Eggplant
- Grape
- Pumpkin
- Yam